# Why does SQL Server take much longer to run this query than SQLite?

Tags: sql-server

I've been writing a process to evaluate computers against specific business rules to figure out it they are eligible to have a product installed on them. I'd initially been working with a small SQLite database, but the project started getting big enough that I'm transitioning it to MS SQL Server. There are about 500k rows in the database.

A query that took about 30 seconds in SQLite is taking close to 30 minutes on the SQL server. I would expect it to be much faster, given that I'm moving to a dedicated server with a lot more system resources.

The query is below. The basic idea is that I have a table with computer information and a table with rules, and different rules need to be compared to different columns in the computer information table. I also need to account for "inclusions" - if a computer has an inclusion rule, that trumps any exclusion rules.

I'm fairly new to SQL in general, so it could just be a badly written query, but it seems to be providing the expected results. It's just so unbearably slow.

```
WITH RulesWith
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Rules
    WHERE
        productName = 'Dlp'
        AND (
            _dateEffective IS NULL
            OR _dateEffective <= '20160906'
            )
        AND (
            _dateExpired IS NULL
            OR _dateExpired >= '20160906'
            )
    )
SELECT C.*
FROM Computers AS C
WHERE (
        (
            C._dateEffective IS NULL
            OR C._dateEffective <= '20160906'
            )
        AND (
            C._dateExpired IS NULL
            OR C._dateExpired >= '20160906'
            )
        )
    AND (
        (
            C.site_name IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'Site'
                    AND typeName = 'Include'
                )
            OR C.computer_fqdn IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'Computer'
                    AND typeName = 'Include'
                )
            OR C.computer_ou IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'ComputerOU'
                    AND typeName = 'Include'
                )
            OR C.user_ou IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'UserOU'
                    AND typeName = 'Include'
                )
            )
        OR NOT (
            C.site_name IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'Site'
                    AND typeName = 'Exclude'
                )
            OR C.computer_fqdn IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE productName = 'MyProduct'
                    AND propertyName = 'Computer'
                    AND typeName = 'Exclude'
                )
            OR C.computer_ou IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'ComputerOU'
                    AND typeName = 'Exclude'
                )
            OR C.user_ou IN (
                SELECT value
                FROM RulesWith
                WHERE propertyName = 'UserOU'
                    AND typeName = 'Exclude'
                )
            )
        )
```

*Edit:* Removing a lot of the UPPER() functions dramatically reduced the query time to about 5 minutes. I'd still like to clean it up further, but that's a huge difference right away.

Comment: Your database is probably for crap.  Who knows what relationships are missing, what indexes don't exist, etc etc etc.  Best thing is to use the database tuning advisor to figure out what you need to fix.

Comment: One thing to do which should help, stop `upper`ing everything - unless you've done something custom, SQL Server will be case-insensitive by default.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the SQL server side?  Your query is going to be doing a table scan even with decent indexes because of your queries.

Comment: For readability, I'd convert the `not (a in b or c in d...)` to the equivalent `a not in b and c not in d`. Mixing `and` and `or` always makes things hard to read.

Comment: Why on earth woudl you ever write queries on one database to be used on a different backend? Different database engines work considerably differently. Large data sets perform differently than small data set and you should never develop against a small data set if your production data will be large. You are comparing apples and oranges if you do this. I woudl never expect than anything that ran on SQLLite woudl bear any relationship at all to anything that ran on SQL server just like I wouldn't try to run Java code as C# code.

Comment: @JoeEnos Thanks, I'll try removing the `upper` functions. SQLite is case-sensitive, so they were necessary.